# How to bind object to array in angular ngfor?

Tags: angular

I have observed that in Angular, the current variable does not match with the options.

The object `{ question: 'q3', answer: '' }` exists in `data.questions`, but it may not be the same reference.

However, is there a way to make it work so that the select element will match the object?

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule],
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{name}}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.io/start">
      Learn more about Angular 
    </a>

    {{current|json}}

    <select
      style="border:3px solid blue;"
      [(ngModel)]="current"
      name="selectedQuestion"
    >
      <option >Select your question</option>
      <option *ngFor="let question of data?.questions" [ngValue]="question">{{ question?.question }}</option>
    </select>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  current = { question: 'q3', answer: '' };

  data = {
    title: 'Select your question from the list',
    questions: [
      { question: 'q1', answer: '' },
      { question: 'q2', answer: '' },
      { question: 'q3', answer: '' },
      { question: 'q4', answer: '' },
      { question: 'q5', answer: '' },
      { question: 'q6', answer: '' },
      { question: 'q7', answer: '' },
      { question: 'q8', answer: '' },
    ],
  };
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-fwmthq?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: What do you mean by "may not be the same reference"?

Comment: true, you have 2 object that have different refference... use current in questions

Answer (score 0):

simply reference the object in the array by `find`

```
  current = this.data.questions.find(e => e.question == 'q3');
```